# I would like to burn a file to a virtual dvd

Tags: dvd, emulation, virtual-drive

a program I am using tracks down my diskdrives and offers to write a dvd image to them.  I would like to be able to write this image on HD in stead of on disk, but I have no option to browse the file system.

Therefore I would like a virtual dvd disk, that is in fact a folder, but that is recognized by the app.  as a real, empty dvd.

I have tried MagicDisk, but it doesn't seem to offer the ability to couple an emulated disk drive to a folder...

Comment: So what you want is program the converts a filesystem to a virtual DVD and then a second program to convert the DVD back to a filesystem?

Comment: basically... : yes, I'm kind of hopeless, SUPER got stuck on the native format of the program (that records television) so I figured I tried out the build in conversion (to dvd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have successfully used [Virtual CD](http://www.virtualcd-online.com/) (which now supports DVD, BluRay etc) to make a virtual CD burner. You can then convert the resulting image file into an ISO and extract the files from it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Total Mounter](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/totalmounter-free-virtual-cddvd-burner-thats-easy-use.htm) is free as opposed to Virtual CD that offers a 30 day trial and pay software.

There is a "pro" and a free version without the "pro" title. You can download the [free version of Total Mounter](http://www.kernsafe.com/download/totalmounter.aspx). Make sure to run the setup as Administrator.