# Virtual DVD writer

Tags: windows-7, burning, virtual-drive

my laptop does not have a DVD driver at all.  But I'd like to convert my video to a DVD format (e.g. Video_TS and Audio_TS).  Is there a Virtual DVD writer out there that can pretend to be a DVD+R or DVD-R or DVD-RW drive?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/126571/i-would-like-to-burn-a-file-to-a-virtual-dvd -- but i think you're looking for **DVD authoring software** to create DVD-format files (in the VIDEO_TS and/or AUDIO_TS folders).  real authoring software will not require a burner drive to create such files, but will either allow creating an ISO containing the authored DVD contents or simply writing the files to the hard-drive in the correct folders.

Answer (score 1):

What video software are you using? Many offer the option to write to .iso instead of a real DVD drive, which will create an image with those folders that you can copy, burn on another computer, or mount in a virtual CD/DVD drive.